# jquery comes from where in play sample zentask

Tags: scala, playframework

I am playing with play sample zentask. it references jquery in the main.scala.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-play-1.7.1.js")"></script>
```

but I can't find the jquery scripts under /public directory. where is it? 
I think I missed some features of Play, that I can't understand how it function here. could someone explain it a little?

Comment: I guess play comes with jQuery included https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/public/javascripts

Comment: It does not. Otherwise it wouldn't put the jQuery file in every app you create by default... but this file is missing in the mentioned sample app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are bundled with Play. The default `Assets` controller will look for the file/resource in the classpath and serve it up from there. I'm not sure of the order, but it either looks in the file system and then the classpath or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at your `conf/routes` file. In my, for example, there are this lines:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

which means, that files, that I reference, must be at `public/...` directory. For you (if you have the same `conf/routes`, your javascripts must be at `ZENTASKS_PROJECT_HOME/public/javascripts/*.js`. Pay attentions, that forder named `javascripts`, not `js` like most web developers do.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/scala/zentasks/public/javascripts ... it's not there.

Comment: Just like Mef said, it is not there; but the sample works; but how?